# symfony2 - Not able to execute webtestcase on home page

Tags: php, symfony

I am getting 'InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty' on the home page of my symfony2 application when I execute the phpunit test on it.  please help.

The path is /student.  I can access /student/1/edit and /student/1/show in my tests, but cannot access just /student.

Here is the test:

```
  public function testindexAction(){
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->followRedirects(true);
        $crawler = $client->request("GET","/student");
       // echo $client->getRequest()->getUri();
      // $this->assertRegExp('/\/student$/', $client->getRequest()->getUri());
       $heading = $crawler->filter('h1')->eq(0)->text();
       $this->assertEquals('Student list',$heading);

    }
```

And the error is :
StudentBundle\Tests\Controller\StudentControllerTest::testindexAction
InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.

```
php app/console router:debug -e test | grep /student 
 student                         ANY         ANY    ANY  /student/                                     
 student_show                    ANY         ANY    ANY  /student/{id}/show                            
 student_new                     ANY         ANY    ANY  /student/new                                  
 student_create                  POST        ANY    ANY  /student/create                               
 student_edit                    ANY         ANY    ANY  /student/{id}/edit                            
 student_update                  POST|PUT    ANY    ANY  /student/{id}/update                          
 student_delete                  POST|DELETE ANY    ANY  /student/{id}/delete
```

Comment: There must be any argument that should not be it type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any redirects on homepage?

try to debug by

```
var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());
```

Comment: i think there is since it goes through the front controller.  vardump errored out saying getcontent() does not exist

Comment: and what do you see if type in console: app/console router:debug -e test | grep /student

Comment: student                         ANY         ANY    ANY  /student/         
 student_show                    ANY         ANY    ANY  /student/{id}/show                    
 student_new                     ANY         ANY    ANY  /student/new
student_create                  POST        ANY    ANY  /student/create   student_edit                    ANY         ANY    ANY  /student/{id}/edit                            
 student_update                  POST|PUT    ANY    ANY  student/{id}/update

Comment: then try: $crawler = $client->request("GET","/student/");

Comment: changing  to /student/ gives the same error:StudentBundle\Tests\Controller\StudentControllerTest::testindexAction
InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.

Comment: but do you see the content when you are requesting http://localdomain/app_test.php/student

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75156/discussion-between-evgeniy-kuzmin-and-user2411276).

Comment: pls put this var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());  before $heading = $crawler->filter('h1')... or even better to comment out the filter to make sure that you see the content with h1 tag

Comment: I think I got the error fixed.  I had bootstrap js and css included in the header file.  I removed the header file and just extended the base.html.twig file and that seemed to have fixed the problem.  thanks @Evgeniy Kuzmin.

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to add the bootstrap files without affecting my tests

Comment: thanks for being patient with me @Evgeniy Kuzmin.  You certainly pointed me in the right direction to debug the output.